# Fliping gravity in Unity3d(3D)

Tags: java, c#, gravity, unity-game-engine

currently I am working on a concept of a 3d platformer that involves flipping gravity. the problem is, I cant find any resources that desciribe how to do it in 3d,all of the feedback I see only describes 2d

**How do I flip the force of gravity in Unity3d?(Be able to walk on ceiling)**

**Feedback is appreciated in advanced ;)**

Comment: The approach will be different if you want everything to be affected by the gravity. If you modify Physics.gravity, all rigidbodies will fall with your player. If you want to create an effect like in Prey where the player can walk the walls and ceilings while the rest remains unaffected, you would have to tweak the player only. Most likely using AddForce.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one :

```
Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 1.0F, 0);
```

Comment: What if i want it to only effect the players rigid body?

Comment: You may have a look here : https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/addforce